# Use of も in this sentence

Tags: word-choice, particles, particle-も

In the following sentence what is meant by the use of も

> 皆さん**も**機会があればフランスに来てください

My rough translation of the sentence is

> If any of you get the chance please try and visit France.

my feeling is that も　is meant to imply something along  the lines of "You all [And others also]" but just want too check I'm not missing any other nuance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the standard *also*.

来てください suggests that the speaker is/has been in France, so it means *You guys also (in addition to me) come to France if you have any chance.*